# How to split a multi-line string containing the characters "\n" into an array of strings in bash?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, escaping

I have a *string* in the following format:

```
I'm\nNed\nNederlander
I'm\nLucky\nDay
I'm\nDusty\nBottoms
```

I would like to move this to an array of strings line by line such that:

```
$ echo "${ARRAY[0]}"
I'm\nNed\nNederlander

$ echo "${ARRAY[1]}"
I'm\nLucky\nDay

$ echo "${ARRAY[2]}"
I'm\nDusty\nBottoms
```

However, I'm running into problems with the "\n" characters within the string itself.  They are represented in the string as two separate characters, the backslash and the 'n', but when I try to do the array split they get interpreted as newlines. Thus typical string splitting with `IFS` does not work.

For example:

```
$ read -a ARRAY <<< "$STRING"
$ echo "${#ARRAY[@]}"   # print number of elements
2

$ echo "${ARRAY[0]}"
I'mnNednNederla

$ echo "${ARRAY[1]}"
der
```

Comment: BTW, does anybody know how to fix SE's terrible formatting of the code above?

Comment: The "terrible formatting" is due to the apostrophes being interpreted as single quotes (which it expects to be balanced). Use the "block quote" tags instead of "code" tags.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default, the `read` builtin allows \ to escape characters. To turn off this behavior, use the `-r` option. It is not often you will find a case where you do not want to use `-r`.

```
string="I'm\nNed\nNederlander
I'm\nLucky\nDay
I'm\nDusty\nBottoms"

arr=()
while read -r line; do
   arr+=("$line")
done <<< "$string"
```

In order to do this in one-line (like you were attempting with `read -a`), actually requires `mapfile` in bash v4 or higher:

```
mapfile -t arr <<< "$string"
```

Comment: yeah for mapfile oneliner :)

Answer (score 17):

`mapfile` is more elegant, but it is possible to do this in one (ugly) line with `read` (useful if you're using a version of bash older than 4):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a arr <<< "$string"
```

Comment: Indeed, and -d option seems crucial to make it work

Comment: One caveat I did not know about when I posted this: the exit status will be non-zero, since a here string will never end with a null character like `read -d ''` will expect.